# How to fix Unhandled promise rejection in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I get an error message I don't know how to fix:

> Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

My code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');

client.login('NzUzNzAwMzQ2MDI2Nzg2ODI2.X1qAJQ.K-2nBZOSxz8k0LAnGmNC_EGaKqQ');
(async () => {

  client.on('message', async (message) => {
    // Voice only works in guilds, if the message does not come from a guild,
    // we ignore it
    if (!message.guild)
      return;

    if (message.content === '/join') {
      // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
      if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
      } else {
        message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
      }
      const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:/Users/vikto/Desktop/FFBot/Audio/gab.mp3');
    }
  });
  throw();
})()

client.login('NzUzNzAwMzQ2MDI2Nzg2ODI2.X1qAJQ.K-2nBZOSxz8k0LAnGmNC_EGaKqQ');
```

Comment: There's no try/catch inside your async callback, and it's throwing an error you aren't catching.

Comment: Is your login a should-be private token? (If so, then it isn't private anymore and you should change it.)

Comment: @JaredSmith I tried that, but it still doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean by "tried it and it didn't work". If the body of your async function is wrapped in a try/catch, you shouldn't have an unhandled rejection. Unless it's coming from something other than what you posted?

Answer (score 1):

you should encompass all that code inside a try catch as there several statements can also produce a rejected promise.